# SWT TableItem: How to remove left padding/ indent?

Tags: java, swt

The following piece of code creates an SWT table with two columns and two rows. On my system, the resulting shell/table looks like this:

[image]

I can't help but wonder where the extra indent/spacing/padding in front of each cell text comes from. I have searched the Web and tried every possible way to remove it, but I cannot find a way. **How do I remove the extra spacing (marked red in the above image)?**

**System information:**

- Linux Mint 17
- SWT 4.4 x86_64

**Links:**

This example is originally taken from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/TableExample.htm) and modified a bit. The screenshot on the original site does not show this spacing/indent.

**Code to reproduce this issue:**

```
public class SwtTableItemIssue {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getDefault());
    shell.setSize(200, 180);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table t = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    t.setHeaderVisible(true);

    TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn(t, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn(t, SWT.NONE);
    tc1.setText("First Name");
    tc2.setText("Last Name");
    tc1.setWidth(70);
    tc2.setWidth(70);

    new TableItem(t, SWT.NONE).setText(new String[] { "Tim", "Hatton" });
    new TableItem(t, SWT.NONE).setText(new String[] { "Caitlyn", "Warner" });

    shell.open();
    shell.layout();

    Display display = Display.getDefault();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }

    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Related/original issue: https://github.com/syncany/syncany/issues/346

Comment: Displays OK on Mac OS X. It looks like space being left for column images, might be a Linux specific issue.

Comment: Works fine on Linux Mint with an older version of SWT. Doesn't work with SWT 4.4 here either.

Comment: The source code of `TableItem` contains this comment: "shifted a bit too far right on later versions of GTK - however, old Tree also had this problem". Not sure if it relates to your issue. If so, they seem to be aware of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, did a bit of research and turns out it's a GTK3 issue.

Since version 4.4, SWT uses GTK3 by default (if available). I've tested your code with GTK3 and GTK2 and it works in the latter.

You've now got three options:

1. Wait for the SWT team to fix it.
2. Fall back to an older SWT version.
3. Force SWT (4.4) to use GTK2 instead of GTK3.

Neither solution is ideal, but I don't see another option.

---

You can force SWT to use GTK2 by setting an environment variable:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Make sure to either make this a permanent setting or run it every time before you start your application.

[Here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/R4_4/new_and_noteworthy.html) are the release notes of SWT 4.4.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I'll use the SWT_GTK3 env variable as a workaround and report it as a bug with SWT; so that maybe they'll fix it in a later release.

Comment: Bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457196 / Just tested SWT_GTK3=0 for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456522 and it works for that one too. The SWT/GTK3 table implementation seems to be a bit buggy.